Flutter & Stripe - Subscription - PaymentSheet cannot set up a PaymentIntent in status 'succeeded'
I have an application written in Flutter and I've implemented one-time payment (for such as game point) in the app by using Stripe SDK 11.0.0. My backend & the application works perfectly for that one-time payment scenario. I see success on my mobile screen, and payment on my Stripe Dashboard
Now I wanted to implement payments for subscriptions.
You can see what I've done so far in my whole viewmodel class for only that scenario:
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/response/Status.dart';
import 'package:my_app/repository/marketing/MarketingRepository.dart';
import 'package:my_app/view_models/user_preference/UserPreference.dart';

class SubscriptionViewModel extends GetxController {
  final _api = MarketingRepository();
  UserPreference userPreference = UserPreference();

  final rxRequestStatus = Status.LOADING.obs;
  RxString clientSecret = ''.obs;
  RxString ephemeralKey = ''.obs;
  RxString customerId = ''.obs;

  /// Handles subscription for all three cases
  Future<void> handleSubscription(String plan) async {
    try {
      var user = await userPreference.getUser();

      // Step 1: Make request to the backend to check for payment method and retrieve necessary information
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        MY_REQUEST_BODY_HERE
      };

      // API call to backend to initiate subscription
      var response = await _api.paymentApi(
        data,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${user.accessToken}"
        },
      );

      // Handle the response based on the status
      if (response["status"] == "requires_payment_method") {
        // Case 1: No payment method available, collect payment details
        print('No payment method available, need to collect payment details');

        await collectPaymentMethod(
            response["setupIntentClientSecret"],
            response["customerId"],
            response["ephemeralKey"],
            plan
        );

      } else if (response["status"] == "success" && response["payload"]["clientSecret"] != null) {
        if (response["payload"]["ephemeralKey"] != null) {
          // Case 2: User has a payment method but it's not the default, retrieve and use it
          print('User has a payment method, but not default.');
          await confirmSubscription(response["payload"]["clientSecret"], response["payload"]["ephemeralKey"], response["payload"]["customerId"]);
        } else {
          // Case 3: User has a default payment method, directly pop up payment sheet
          print('User has a default payment method. Confirming subscription.');
          await confirmSubscription(response["payload"]["clientSecret"], "", response["payload"]["customerId"]);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during subscription: $e');
      if (e is StripeException) {
        print('Stripe error: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      } else {
        print('Unexpected error: $e');
      }
    }
  }

  /// Collect payment method when none is available (Case 1)
  Future<void> collectPaymentMethod(String setupIntentClientSecret, String customerId, String ephemeralKey, String plan) async {
    try {
      // Initialize payment sheet for collecting new payment method
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          customFlow: false,
          merchantDisplayName: 'My Store',
          setupIntentClientSecret: setupIntentClientSecret,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
          customerId: customerId,
        ),
      );

      // Present the payment sheet for the user to enter payment details
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

      print('Payment method successfully added!');

      // Retrieve the payment method from the SetupIntent after the payment sheet is completed
      final paymentMethodId = await retrievePaymentMethodIdFromSetupIntent(setupIntentClientSecret);

      if (paymentMethodId != null) {
        print('PaymentMethodId: $paymentMethodId');

        // Send the paymentMethodId to the backend to set it as default and complete the subscription
        var user2 = await userPreference.getUser();

        // Step 1: Make request to the backend to check for payment method and retrieve necessary information
        Map<String, dynamic> data2 = {
          MY_REQUEST_BODY_HERE
          'paymentMethodId': paymentMethodId,
        };

        // API call to backend to initiate subscription
        await _api.paymentApi(
          data2,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer ${user2.accessToken}"
          },
        );

        // Show successful subscription
        Get.snackbar('Success', 'Subscription completed successfully!');
      }

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error collecting payment method: $e');
      if (e is StripeException) {
        print('Stripe error: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      } else {
        print('Unexpected error: $e');
      }
    }
  }

  /// Helper method to retrieve the paymentMethodId from a SetupIntent
  Future<String?> retrievePaymentMethodIdFromSetupIntent(String setupIntentClientSecret) async {
    try {
      // Fetch the SetupIntent to retrieve the attached payment method
      final setupIntent = await Stripe.instance.retrieveSetupIntent(setupIntentClientSecret);
      if (setupIntent.paymentMethodId != null) {
        return setupIntent.paymentMethodId; // Retrieve the payment method ID
      } else {
        print('No payment method was found in the SetupIntent.');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error retrieving payment method from SetupIntent: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  /// Confirm subscription for users with a payment method (Case 2 & Case 3)
  Future<void> confirmSubscription(String clientSecret, String ephemeralKey, String customerId) async {
    try {
      // Initialize payment sheet for confirmation
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          customFlow: false,
          merchantDisplayName: 'My Store',
          paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,  // This will be empty for default payment methods
          customerId: customerId,
        ),
      );

      // Present the payment sheet to confirm the subscription
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((e) {
        Stripe.instance.confirmPaymentSheetPayment();
      });

      print('Subscription confirmed successfully!');

      // Show successful subscription
      Get.snackbar('Success', 'Subscription completed successfully!');

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error confirming subscription: $e');
      if (e is StripeException) {
        print('Stripe error: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      } else {
        print('Unexpected error: $e');
      }
    }
  }
}

When I hit my button, it hits the handleSubscription method. Simply, it sends request to my backend with a body includes some parameters.
If I hit at first time, my backend returns me like this;
{
  "customerId": "cus_Qy9...",
  "ephemeralKey": "ek_test_YWN...",
  "message": "Customer has no default payment method. Please provide a payment method.",
  "setupIntentClientSecret": "seti_1Q6...",
  "status": "requires_payment_method"
}

In my code, it joins to Case1 (which means collectPaymentMethod). And I see my screen like this:

I guess I do correct because if I enter test card number and hit Set Up button, I see button as green with green tick, and then I see my subscription on my Stripe dashboard.
Then, if I cancel my subscription from Stripe Dashboard, and, if I try second time with another subscription from my app, my backend returns a response to me like this:
{
  "payload": {
    "clientSecret": "pi_3Q6...",
    "customerId": "cus_Qy9...",
    "ephemeralKey": "ek_test_YWN...",
    "id": "sub_1Q6...",
    "status": "active"
  },
  "status": "success",
  "transaction_type": "subscription"
}

But on my screen, I see a loading spinner, then it disappears. I see like this:

On my logs, I see those;
I/flutter (21575): User has a payment method, but not default.
I/ContentCaptureHelper(21575): Setting logging level to OFF
I/flutter (21575): Error confirming subscription: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: PaymentSheet cannot set up a PaymentIntent in status 'succeeded'.
I/flutter (21575): See https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status., message: PaymentSheet cannot set up a PaymentIntent in status 'succeeded'.
I/flutter (21575): See https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status., stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))
I/flutter (21575): Stripe error: PaymentSheet cannot set up a PaymentIntent in status 'succeeded'.
I/flutter (21575): See https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status.
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(21575): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$Api34Impl$createOnBackAnimationCallback$1@a9a0ae4

Strange part is; I see my new subscription on Stripe Dashboard.
1st question;
At Case1, I see the button as "Set Up". Is this correct and everything is correct?
2nd question;
Since I see error logs & just a spinner and disappears on my mobile but success subscription on Stripe Dashboard, can you tell mewhat am I missing? What am I doing wrong?
If you think everything is correct on my mobile flutter side, I can edit the question and add my backend codes here.

I didn't review your entire code snippet since you really should share just the sections where you're running into issues. You also didn't share the server-side code that's creating the Subscription object.
Based on what you have shared, it looks like you're creating a Subscription for an existing Customer object, and likely with collection_method: charge_automatically. Upon Subscription creation, Stripe tries to collect payment on the first Invoice, which fails if the Customer doesn't have a value for invoice_settings.default_payment_method. This brings you to Case 1 where I think you try to use the Subscription's pending_setup_intent to collect payment details.
I assume the step you took to create another Subscription was for the same Customer ("cus_Qy9...") and that the previously-saved card was saved as their default payment method. The reason you see the error and the loading spinner that disappears is likely because your code is attempting to render the PaymentSheet using the client secret for an already-confirmed PaymentIntent. If you detect that the Subscription's latest invoice has been paid, there's no need to present a PaymentSheet; you should direct your customer to some "Success!" page instead or a page that shows details about their newly-created Subscription.

I understand the logic. But the question is; assume that there is a user that cancelled his subscription, then decided to buy new subscription. Since my code throws StripeException, how can I handle the Success ?

I think your code should look at the status of the Subscription and/or the status of the Subscription's latest Invoice. If the Subscription's status after creation is active or if the latest Invoice is in paid status, there's no need to present the payment sheet
